# how can I bring the dropdown list in front other component, I had tried every thing I know, but I failed to solve this error please help out

Tags: css

> below code is the html code for the navbar dropdown list issue please help me out

```
HTML:
            <div class="nav-menu" id="myNavmenu">
             <a href="index.html">
               <img src="../images/logo.png" width="150" alt="Logo">
                 </a>
                 <a href="index.html">Home </a>
                <div class="dropdown">
                 <button class="dropbtn"><a href="about.html">About</a> 
                  <span class="menu_icon fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                   </button>
                  <div class="dropdown-content">
                  </div>
```

> below is the CSS part for my code I'm facing issue regarding dropdown
> list in navbar

CSS:

```
    .dropdown {position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
               }
       
      .dropdown-content {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: #555353;
          min-width: 150px;
          left: 0;
          top: 100%;
          width: 300px; 
          z-index: 1; 
        }
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
      font-size: 15px;    
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: rgb(70, 66, 66);
      /* padding: 14px 16px; */
      background-color: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      margin: 0;
    }
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  
}
```

Comment: Please add the html code

Comment: As @ATP said, we need the HTML code to find out what's your issue. But I'm afraid the `display: none;` at `.dropdown-content` class is the culprit.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: You need to show the HTML as well as the CSS as they work together. Only showing one, can be difficult to fix as the error may be in the other.

Answer (score 1):

You're hidding the dropdown content by default when using `display: none;`.

You can display the content when hovering the dropdown by adding this to your CSS.

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
```

Comment: I used the .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    } but its of no use, the same issue I'm facing